# Почему не ищутся билеты по названию?

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте умнейшие люди. В общем пишу я название городов в поля поиска и пустота. Пишу значит я их id и норм, билеты выводится. I can't understand.

Форма поиска:

```
<main id="main">
<div id="search">
    <form id="searchh" action="{{route('search')}}" method="get">
        <p id="bilet">Поиск билетов</p>
        <div id="search1">
            <input type="search" name="city_departure" id="search12" placeholder="Откуда">
            <input type="search" name="city_arrival" id="search2" placeholder="Куда">
            <input type="date" name="day_date">
            <button type="submit">Найти</button>
            <input id="search" type="hidden" name="search" value="{{Request::get('search')}}">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Вывод билета:

```
                        @foreach($items as $tickets)
        <div class="flights">
            <form action="/buy{{$tickets->id}}" method="get">
                        <div class="info1">
                            Купе от: {{$tickets->price }}₽
                            <p>CВ от: {{$tickets->price }}₽</p>
                            <p>Поезд: {{$tickets->train_id }}</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="info2">
                       <div class="gorod">
                           {{ $tickets->city->name }}
                        -------->
                        {{ $tickets->city1->name}}</div>
                        <p class="timee">Время отправления: {{$tickets->time_departure}}ч.</p>
                        <p class="timee">Время в пути: {{$tickets->time_trip}}ч.</p>
                        <p>Дата:  {{ $tickets->date}}</p>
                        <button class ='buy'>Выбрать место</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="ti" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="buy">
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Контроллер:

```
  public function search(Request $request)
{
    $UserController = new UserController();
    $UserController->authUser();
    $data = (object)[
        'role' => $UserController->user_role,
    ];

    $items = Trip::when($request->get('day_date'), function($query, $date){ $query->where('date', $date); })
        ->when($request->get('price'), function($query, $price){ $query->where('price', $price); })
        ->when($request->get('train_id'), function($query, $train_id){ $query->where('train_id', $train_id); })
        ->when($request->get('time_departure'), function($query, $time_departure){ $query->where('time_departure', $time_departure); })
        ->when($request->get('city_departure'), function($query, $departure_id){ $query->where('departure_id', $departure_id); })
        ->when($request->get('city_arrival'), function($query, $landing_id){ $query->where('landing_id', $landing_id); })
        ->when($request->get('day_date'), function($query, $date){ $query->where('date', $date); })

        ->get();
```

Comment: Во первых при чём тут веб дизайн и разработка?? Это вам к фотошопу и иллюстратору надо.  Во вторых, а откуда возьмётся название если поиск по id идёт??  `->when($request->get('train_id'), function($query, $train_id){ $query->where('train_id', $train_id); })` вот в этой строчке ваш ответ на вопрос почему id работает

Comment: А кто тогда? Train_id это номер поезда, который повезет. Я тут накосячил немног в вопросе, щас исправлю.

Comment: ну у вас же всё написано. Вы вводите название в `city_departure` например.  А на бэке у вас поиск по id идёт `function($query, $departure_id){ $query->where('departure_id', $departure_id); })` Понятное дело если будете вводить всё что отличное от id будет возвращать пустой массив. city_arrival та же проблема будет